# Dispatching on the class of a value in Java, is there a better way?

Tags: java

I'm using PubNub in Java and you essentially sub-class from `SubscribeCallback` to implement receiving a message. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class SubscribeCallback {
    public abstract void status(PubNub pubnub, PNStatus status);

    public abstract void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult message);

    public abstract void presence(PubNub pubnub, PNPresenceEventResult presence);
}
```

My messages are all of different classes with different payloads all inheriting from a `Message` class, so, my `message` method looks something like this:

```
@Override
final public void message(PubNub pubnub, PNMessageResult messageResult) {
    Message message = getMessage(messageResult);
    if (message instanceof DisplayerChanged) { 
         message((DisplayerChanged) message);
    } else if (message instanceof DisplayersChanged) {
        message((DisplayersChanged) message);
    } else if (message instanceof NewScreenshotsToRender) {
        message((NewScreenshotsToRender) message);
    } else if (message instanceof RendererChanged) {
        message((RendererChanged) message);
    } else if (message instanceof RenderersChanged) {
        message((RenderersChanged) message);
    } else if (message instanceof ScreenshotRendered) {
        message((ScreenshotRendered) message);
    } else if (message instanceof SitesChanged) {
        message((SitesChanged) message);
    } else if (message instanceof UsersChanged) {
        message((UsersChanged) message);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Received unexpected message type: " + messageResult);
    }
}
```

This looks horrible. Is there a better way of doing this dispatch?

The reason why I'm calling another method called `message` is so that different apps can inherit from this class and override `message` for the particular class of message it wants to handle.

Comment: Take a look at the Visitor pattern

Comment: @Kayaman: how is this a duplicate of that question? That question is about lacking a cast to have the proper method called. I'm clearly doing that casting so the proper method is called.

Comment: Project Amber will solve this eventually!

Comment: @Pablo it explains the issue and the standard way of solving double dispatch with the Visitor pattern. Were you expecting a different solution? There really isn't one.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't really see how these questions are related.

Comment: @Arash do you understand double dispatch?

Comment: I do understand double dispatch. This is a very specific design question. That question is from completely different perspective.

Comment: Looks appropriate to me. Each of your `Message` types should have a method that accepts an argument of the `SubscribeCallback` subtype and invokes the appropriate `message(..)` method, `message(this)`.

Comment: To me this looks like a textbook example. I have a hard time seeing anything special in this.